# (Typos in Oracle tutorial?) Accessing local variables of the enclosing scope from a lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda, scope

Yes, there are many similar questions on this topic,
but I want to clarify if the official tutorial should be modified or not.

In the Oracle Java Tutorial https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html,

below the subtitle "Accessing Local Variables of the Enclosing Scope",

it says:

> Because of this assignment statement, the variable `FirstLevel.x` is not
> effectively final anymore. As a result, the Java compiler generates an
> error message similar to "local variables referenced from a lambda
> expression must be final or effectively final" where the lambda
> expression myConsumer tries to access the `FirstLevel.x` variable:
>
> System.out.println("x = " + x);

In the above paragraph, doesn't this `FirstLevel.x` need correction?

I thought it needs to be modified to `parameter x of methodInFirstLevel`, not `FirstLevel.x`.

Because, the lambda expression does not introduce a new level of scoping, but a normal method(`methodInFirstLevel` in this case) does make a new level of scope.

Did I get this wrong?

(I've tried to describe this question correctly in the title & body, but please let me know if this question should be modified.)

Comment: You have found a bug in the tutorial.  Report it!

Comment: @Stephen, thanks for commenting! I'm a newbie and really don't know if you're joking or not :) If it's not joking, could you please tell me how to report it? I googled but bug reporting seems quite difficult for programming newbies.

Comment: No, I am not joking.  But it is not difficult to submit a Java bug report either.  Just go here >> https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/ << and follow the instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. I would phrase it as:

> the **parameter variable `x`** is not effectively final anymore.